# CKEditor's dialog textarea is not editable

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

So I'm making my own plugin to the ckeditor, since I need a special case. Anyway, I can't make textarea element editable. This is my whole code to my own dialog (for the plugin):

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add('myDialog', function(editor) {
    return {
        title: 'My Plugin',
        minWidth: 750,
        minHeight: 500,
        onShow: function(evt) {
            var selection = editor.getSelection();
            var widget = editor.widgets.selected[0];
            var element = !!widget && !!widget.parts ? widget.parts['my'] : false;
            var command = this.getName();

            if(command == 'myDialog') {
                var code = selection.getSelectedElement();

                if(code && !!element) {
                    this.setupContent(code);
                    widget.data.myinput = element.getHtml();
                }
            }
        },
        contents: [{
            id: 'info',
            label: 'Info',
            accessKey: 'I',
            elements: [{
                id: 'myinput',
                type: 'textarea',
                required: true,
                label: 'Content',
                rows: 42,
                setup: function(widget) {
                    this.setValue(widget.data.myinput);
                },
                commit: function(widget) {
                    widget.setData('myinput', this.getValue());
                }
            }]
        }],
    };
});
```

Problem is only within `contents.myinput`. It type is textarea but when I open the dialog its not editable. When I change type to the text and remove rows, then text input shows up, working great and so on. Only textarea is problem. This is how it looks like after opening the dialog:

[image]

Version of my CKEditor is 4.5. I already made 3 plugins before, but never had to use textarea so all other plugins works except this one. I would append jsFiddle, if there was any site offering "ckeditor plugin tester" so I just post my code.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that I init ckeditor in the bootstrap's dialog. So the solution for my problem is to apply the following lines of code after initialization:

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {
    var $modalElement = this.$element;

    $(document).on('focusin.modal', function(e) {
        var $parent = $(e.target.parentNode);
        if($modalElement[0] !== e.target
                && !$modalElement.has(e.target).length
                && !$parent.hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_select')
                && !$parent.hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_text')
                && !$parent.hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_textarea')) {
            $modalElement.focus();
        }
    })
};
```

I had this code before the problem, but I was missing `!$parent.hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_textarea')` which I forget to add, so this was my fault :)